# Create Java Annotation Wrapper

Tags: java, annotations, wrapper

I am currently using an annotation provided by a 3rd party library and I'm wondering if there is a way to create another 'wrapper annotation' around it so that I don't have to require all parameters.

For example I can use the library annotation like this:

```
@LibraryAnnotation(Parameter1, Parameter2, Parameter3)
```

But in my case Parameter2 and Parameter3 are always the same so I want to create an annotation that will only take in Parameter1

```
@MyAnnotation(Parameter1)
```

But will call the other annotation with all Parameters, similar to how you might create a wrapper for a 3rd party method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Annotations are quite limited. Unfortunately, I don't see a way, but I might be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

My original tests was like this:

```
@Test
@SqlGroup(
    {
        @Sql(
            executionPhase = BEFORE_TEST_METHOD,
            config = @SqlConfig(transactionMode = ISOLATED),
            scripts = {"classpath:test/sqls/_truncate_tables.sql"}
        ),
        @Sql(
            executionPhase = AFTER_TEST_METHOD,
            config = @SqlConfig(transactionMode = ISOLATED),
            scripts = {"classpath:test/sqls/_truncate_tables.sql"}
        )
    }
)
public void countTeams_countOnEmptyTable_returnsWithEmptyList() {}
```

And whit this base annotation I cleaned up the test files:

```
 @Target({ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD})
 @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
 @Documented
 @Inherited
 @SqlGroup(
        {
            @Sql(
                executionPhase = BEFORE_TEST_METHOD,
                config = @SqlConfig(transactionMode = ISOLATED),
                scripts = {"classpath:test/sqls/_truncate_tables.sql"}
            ),
            @Sql(
                executionPhase = AFTER_TEST_METHOD,
                config = @SqlConfig(transactionMode = ISOLATED),
                scripts = {"classpath:test/sqls/_truncate_tables.sql"}
            )
        }
)
```

And finally I got this clean version:

```
@Test
@BaseSqlGroup
public void countTeams_countOnEmptyTable_returnsWithEmptyList(){}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there are two options that can be currently used to do this:

- Use the Daileon tool (http://daileon.sourceforge.net/) - since it is more of an experimental tool, its usability is a little bit cumbersome
- Use Aspect-oriented Programming and Inter-Type Declarations to inject a new annotation, e.g.:

  `declare @type : @MyAnnotation package.* : @LibraryAnnotation(..);`

However, both options are quite limiting.

Answer (score 0):

You can annotate your annotation with base annotation like in this sample:

```
@Target(value = {ElementType.TYPE})
@Page(method3="someValue")
public @interface Move {
 String method1();
 String method2();
}

@Target(value = {ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE})
public @interface Page{
 String method3();
}
```

Comment: Please explain more. In your example is the @Page annotation is the @LibraryAnnotation? Does this only/ always work if the @LibraryAnnotation has `@Target(value = {ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE})`?